# Is it possible to deploy a yeoman app to heroku without grunt build?

Tags: angularjs, heroku, yeoman, bower

Is it possible to deploy a yeoman app to heroku without running grunt build?

I successfully deployed the app on heroku using grunt build. But I always make daily changes and it takes time to build the app. I want to deploy the raw app without build, I tried it but the bower_components was missing.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste your `bower_components` folder inside the `/app` folder, this should resolve the dependencies used in your `app/index.html`.

e.g.

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
```

Copy and paste those files only in a similar directory stucture in you `/app` folder.

folder structure:

```
-- app
   -- bower_components
      -- angular
         -- angular.js
      -- angular-resource
         -- angular-resource.js
```

Comment: I think it's better to build the project than copying the entire bower_components and upload it on heroku.

Comment: As I understand your question, you want to upload your **unbuild** app version to heroku?

Comment: You don't have to necessarily upload all bower_component files, simply push the files in the directory structure required in your `index.html`.

Comment: Oh I get it now. I'll just upload the missing bower components(console errors). I'll get back on you if it works.